# Knockout Custom Binding handler inside template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I've created a custom binding handler to render an html select component.

EG:

```
 <select data-bind="dynamicSelect: { src:  'Category', label: 'Category'} "></select>
```

After a user selects a category, the category fields array gets populated, which i have bound to a div that'll render a certain template

```
  <div data-bind="template: { name: displayMode, foreach: categoryFields }"></div>
```

**My templates**

```
<script type="text/html" id="inputTemplate">
    <label data-bind="text: FieldName, attr: { for: FieldName }"></label>
    <input data-bind="attr: { name: FieldName, type: $parent.fieldType($data) }" />
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="lookupTemplate">
    <label data-bind="text: FieldName, attr: { for: FieldName }"></label>
    <select data-bind="dynamicSelect: { src: FieldName, label: FieldName}"></select>
</script>
```

The problem is, that the dynamicSelect inside the template does not seem to be binding? How would i go about reusing a binding handler inside a template?

**Binding handler**

```
define(['durandal/composition', 'plugins/http'], function (composition, http) {
    composition.addBindingHandler('dynamicSelect', {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            console.log(element);
            console.log(valueAccessor());
            var elem = $(element);
            elem.addClass('hidden');
            elem.before('<label>' + valueAccessor().label + '</label>');
            elem.after('<div><br/><label><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin active"></i> Loading...</label></div>');

            console.log('/api/lookup?type=' + valueAccessor().src);
            return http.get('/api/lookup?type=' + valueAccessor().src).then(function (res) {
                var items = res.LookupItems;
                $.each(items, function (idx) {
                    elem.append('<option value=' + items[idx].Id + '>' + items[idx].Name + '</option>');
                });
                elem.removeClass('hidden');
                elem.next().addClass('hidden');
            });

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Curious question, when we have the ability to use KO why are you using  jQuery to render the view?

Comment: I'm still new-ish to knockout, so this was my best attempt... can you possibly provide code/link for this other way of handling my view, or supply code along with you suggestion perhaps? all i know is at the moment the call does not seem to be executing during the template bind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem.

I registered the binding handler using Durandals, composition helper. Thus (and its my best guess), it only got called during the page's creation. Explains why my first select got populated.

I changed my binding handler to

```
define(['plugins/http'], function (http) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.dynamicSelect = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var elem = $(element);
            elem.addClass('hidden');
            elem.before('<label>' + valueAccessor().label + '</label>');
            elem.after('<div><br/><label><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin active"></i> Loading...</label></div>');

            console.log('/api/lookup?type=' + valueAccessor().src);
            return http.get('/api/lookup?type=' + valueAccessor().src).then(function (res) {
                var items = res.LookupItems;
                $.each(items, function (idx) {
                    elem.append('<option value=' + items[idx].Id + '>' + items[idx].Name + '</option>');
                });
                elem.removeClass('hidden');
                elem.next().addClass('hidden');
            });    
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your durandal releated question, but it addresses your lack of MVVM mindset in your code. :D

I would do it has a ViewModel

```
MyApp.LookupViewModel = function(label, src) {
    this.label = label;
    this.src = src;
    this.items = ko.observableArray();   
    this.selectedItem = ko.observable();    
    this.loading = ko.observable(true);
    this.loaded = ko.computed(function() {
        return !this.loading();
    }, this);


    //simulate ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.items([{
                name: "Foo1",
                id: 1
            },{
                name: "Foo2", 
                id: 2
            }

        ]);
        this.loading(false);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
};
```

When you want to use it you just declare an instance of the VM

```
MyApp.ViewModel = function() {
    this.lookup = new MyApp.LookupViewModel("Foo", "http://foo");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vjzn6/1/

My above fiddle uses a little lib of mine that takes care of finding the view names so that you do not need to explicit declare template bindings in your view.

Comment: renamed options > items to distinct in from UI